# Extract Array Formula from data with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following table containing Laptop details

```
(Laptops)
Name                  |  RAM   |  CPU
===========================================
Laptop Example 1      | 4      | Intel® Core™ i3-8130U   
Laptop Example 2      | 8      | Intel® Core™ i5-8250U 
Laptop Example 3      | 16     | Intel® Core™ i5-8250U
Laptop Example 4      | 8      | Intel® Core™ i7-8550U
Laptop Example 5      | 8      | Intel® Core™ i5-8265U
...
```

I was looking to create an array using multiple criteria to simply return the `name` of the laptop. In this case I want to return the name of a laptop with `8` `RAM` & a `CPU` containing `i5-`.

In this table above I would expect to return

```
(Array)
Name                  
====================== 
Laptop Example 2       
Laptop Example 5
```

I haven't had much experience with array formulas but I have been able to either return all laptop names with `8` `RAM`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Laptops!A$2:A$500,SMALL(IF(Laptops!$B$2:$B$500=8,ROW(Laptops!A$2:A$500)-ROW(Laptops!A$2)+1),ROWS(Laptops!A$2:A2))),"")
```

or `CPU` containing `i5-`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Laptops!A$2:A$500,SMALL(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("i5-", Laptops!$C$2:$C$500), 0),ROW(Laptops!A$2:A$500)-ROW(Laptops!A$2)+1),ROWS(Laptops!A$2:A2))),"")
```

But unable to combine both using the `AND` function? I have tried...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Laptops!A$2:A$500,SMALL(IF(AND(Laptops!$B$2:$B$500="8",IFERROR(SEARCH("i5-", Laptops!$C$2:$C$500), 0),ROW(Laptops!A$2:A$500)-ROW(Laptops!A$2)+1),ROWS(Laptops!A$2:A2))),""))
```

However, it does not return anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pivot table and then filter on RAM and apply a filter to the CPU column.

Some help in doing that [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-cc1ed287-3a97-4e95-b377-ddfafe79fa8f)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My aproach to you question would be like this

**1.- Get some auxiliar columns**

Add a column "CPU Family"

```
=left(right(C2;8);2)
```

You can duplicate the Ram field if you which to see the ram when you filter

```
=B2&"gb"
```

**2.- Insert Pivot Table**

Select the whole range of data, CTRL+SHIFT+Space and go to Insert > Pivot Table

Here you would select `Ram` and `CPU Family` as your filters, On the Label Fields you would add `Laptop Name` and `CPU`

[image]

Translation: `=LEFT(RIGHT(C2;8);2)`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my approach without involving `VBA`

Cheers.